# SourceTree Git Error: "fatal: unable to read" after changing directory

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I recently changed my primary HDD after my old one died, so my local project files are now under a new path with a new drive letter. When I opened SourceTree, it prompted me to select the path of this repository.

I did so, and it's been giving me this error when it tries to read the repository: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIKhB.png

The `'git status' failed with code 128` part seems to be talking about Windows line endings, but the `fatal: unable to read` part suggests that there's something wrong with the repository itself. I'm not sure why this would happen because the folder was simply copied over from my old HDD. The `.git` folder is still there.

Comment: Can you try again after a `git config --global core.autocrlf false`?

Comment: Thanks, just tried. The line endings problem went away but the other error msg remained: https://i.imgur.com/aJzN8o9.png

Comment: Can you try a `git status` in command line in the folder of your repo?

Comment: It's giving me the same `fatal: unable to read` error. Do you think the repository just got corrupted somehow? I'm not sure what would've caused that.

Comment: Yes, if the repo doesn't respond well in command-line, it won't be any better with SourceTree. the first thing to do is trying to clone it again.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I push my local files to the remote repository then? If I clone from remote to local, won't the remote files overwrite my local files as the "latest" version? I can also create a new local repository and push that, but I'm not sure how to delete the old one without losing non-git files.

Comment: I would recommend cloning to a different folder, for testing. That way, you don't overwrite anything locally.